# Is there a ready to use jQuery plugin that shows electricity label

Tags: jquery, popup, modal-dialog, jquery-dialog

I need to show a label (modal dialog) that shows the current electricity consumption. On hover it shows the full electricity label as on the picture below:

[image]

Move over the text should support translation in multiple languages.

Comment: You'll find plugins to show popups on hover but the content is up to you I think.

Comment: I doubt there is a ready-made plugin for this very specific use case.